# Remove multiple linebreaks

Tags: java

How can I remove multiple linebreaks from a string so I only get one linebreak if any. For example I have a string with `"\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"`, how can I turn that into a single `'\n'` ?

Comment: If they're on the end of a String, `trim()` will remove all whitespace nicely. If inside of a String, then `replaceAll(...)` using regex will work great. **edit**: as noted by @Reimeus. 1+ to him.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could use:

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("[\r\n]+", "\n");
```

Comment: To the original poster, the first parameter is a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), and that's what gives this method its power. 1+ up-vote.

Comment: you could also consider making the `\r` optional in the search regex.  That way `\n\n\n` could also be reduced to `\n`.  Nitpicking I know.  EDIT: Nevermind, because the characters inside the brackets are optional as pointed out by @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: @Marty: it **is** optional in the above regex since he is using a [character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html), so your nitpick is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

In Android I managed to remove more than 2 line breaks with this

```
textPiece = textPiece.replaceAll("\n\n\n+", "\n\n");
```