# How do i replace a double line with a single line in a string in Android?

Tags: java, android, string, replace, line-breaks

I have a string:

```
 This is a test sentence 1.
 This is a test sentence 2.
 This is a test sentence 3.

 This is a test sentence 4.

 This is a test sentence 5.
```

I would like to replace the double line gap with a single line instead. Such as:

```
 This is a test sentence 1.
 This is a test sentence 2.
 This is a test sentence 3.
 This is a test sentence 4.
 This is a test sentence 5.
```

However, I do not know how to detect the double line break, "\n" works when replacing a single line break but i have tried "\n\n" in a replace function with no success.

```
textView.setText(string.replaceAll("\n\n","\n"));
```

Comment: That last line should have worked. Looks fine to me.

Comment: I mean it works if you know all the new lines are sequential.  You need a whitespace class.

Comment: It seems "\n\n" is not being detected. As i replaced it with "T" and received many new lines.

Comment: You should use the system line separator (`System.getProperty("line.separator")`, or in Java 7: `System.lineSeparator()`) like so: `String newline = /* line separator */; textView.setText(string.replaceAll(newline + newline, newline));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
str.replaceAll("[\r\n]+", "\n")
```

Source: [Remove multiple linebreaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124859/remove-multiple-linebreaks)

Comment: You should use the system line separator (`System.getProperty("line.separator")`, or in Java 7: `System.lineSeparator()`).

Comment: @Jashaszun what is the reason for this?

Comment: @jamesgates1 So that if the system line separator is `\r\n` this will work appropriately.

Comment: You probably need to include newlines followed by whitespace characters: `"str.replaceAll("([\r\n][\r\n\s]*", "\n");`

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code, It will replace the double lines to single line.

```
string = Pattern.compile("[\r\n]+").matcher(string).replaceAll("\n");
textView.setText(string);
```

or

```
 string = string.replaceAll("[\r\n]+", "\n");
 textView.setText(string);
```

Both should give the same result.